# How do I change the date format to make them appear as May 12?

Tags: views, datetime

I want to view the date as "May 12" (month day).

What should I type in the custom format for date in this case?

Comment: M y, but http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php will give you that information as well as all the other formatting date() can do

Comment: M j is Month Day.  M y is Month YR as in the example page originally cited in the question (or maybe I read it wrong since it's not listed here now).

Comment: where do you want the date to be displayed?

Comment: @meekahu Please post the answer  , So that this question will be removed from the "unanswered list"